# An interesting paper on hunter-gatherer social dynamics and cooperation

Tags: evolution, literature, sociality, gender

I've read a paper long ago on the cooperativeness in the hunter-gatherer primitive societies. Their conclusion is that for hunters, cooperation dominates competition; for gatherers, competition dominates cooperation. Some of their arguments are:

1. Cooperation is necessary in hunting activities, especially in hunting large beasts; cooperation is less necessary in gathering activities.
2. The location abundant of fruits is static and limited. Gatherers must compete for that location. However, the herds are usually moving and large.
3. The easy location for gathering is strictly limited, meaning that, if one gatherer collected most of fruits from that location, other gatherers have nothing left. For hunters there is another story. One good hunter may collect one buffalo from the herd, and this does not prevent another hunter to collect anther buffalo from the same herd: the resource is relatively not the limiting factor, the limitation factor is the cooperative-hunting skill

I cannot remember all information precisely as it's been a long time. The problem is that I forgot the exact citation of that paper. What are some related paper in literature?